# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement PrincipalContext with multiple application under default website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am setting up a new authentication using Active Directory on our domain, but we have older applications that run under the main website that are in .Net 4 and .Net 2 and sadly even a few items still in Classic ASP (I blame management on that, if it does not bring in money it stays). Anyway I have the root of the site in MVC 5 with .Net 4.7.1 and all of the controllers and WebApi calls work fine with the PrincipalContext, but if I try to redirect to another application under the root running on either the same App Pool or even a different one I get routed back to my login controller/view as if I am not logged in even though I can confirm that I am logged in and can get to the MVC controllers/views that are secured.

If I use the older style of FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe) and make sure the web.config in the .Net 4 and .Net 2 applications have the same machine key as the MVC, everything works fine. At this point I have not been able to find a way to use the MachineKey in the config. Note that all of these applications are on the same machine, same root website so there is no actual cross domain.

Comment: How did you authenticate a user in MVC 5 application?

Comment: @Win see this [link](https://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/)

Comment: Cookie Authentication Middleware is not compatible with Form Authentication. You will need to use Form Authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5 app.